# Slow Download Speeds

Tags: networking, firefox, downloads

I have been having some issues with slow download speeds while running 16.10. When I run a speedtest, it is showing somewhere around 20 Mbps, but when I go to download a file it is crawling by at a few hundred kbps. I have noticed this problem while using firefox, chrome, and transmission, while on my home network and on my work network, and while using wired and wireless connections. For instance I tried to download the iso of a 32 bit version of ubuntu for a different machine and it estimated 20 hours and eventually fails downloading. When I switched to windows 10, it only took about 15 - 20 minutes to download.